# What is root CGROUP?

Tags: linux, cgroups

[here](https://lwn.net/Articles/606699/)  it is mentioned:

> In the classic mode, which may ultimately be deprecated, but is still fully supported, there can be several separate cgroup hierarchies. Each hierarchy starts its life as a **root cgroup**, which initially holds all processes.

---

What is root CGROUP? In a Linux process model.

Answer (score 2):

Your article is talking about "classic" vs. "unified" ([cgroup v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt)) cgroups:

> https://lwn.net/Articles/606699/
>
> As was recently reported, the 3.16 Linux kernel will have
>   under-development support for a so-called "unified hierarchy". The new
>   ideas introduced with that development will not be discussed yet, as
>   we cannot really appreciate what value they might bring until we fully
>   understand what we have....
>
> In the classic mode, which may ultimately be deprecated, but is still
>   fully supported, there can be several separate cgroup hierarchies.
>   Each hierarchy starts its life as a root cgroup, which initially holds
>   all processes. This root node is created by mounting an instance of
>   the "cgroup" virtual filesystem and all further modifications to the
>   hierarchy happen through manipulations of this filesystem,...
>
> This is a very "organizational" way to manipulate a hierarchy: create
>   a new group and find someone to fill it....

Here is a good article on the current status of v2 adoption (for example, viz. the Docker community):

> [The current adoption status of cgroup v2 in
>   containers](https://medium.com/nttlabs/cgroup-v2-596d035be4d7)
>
> Fedora 31 was released on October 29, 2019. This is the first major
>   distro that comes with cgroup v2 (aka unified hierarchy) enabled by
>   default, 5 years after it first appeared in Linux kernel 3.16 (Aug 3, 2014).
>
> While the adoption of cgroup v2 is an inevitable step toward
>   2020s, most container implementations including Docker/Moby and
>   Kubernetes still don’t support cgroup v2...

OK: to your question - "What is root CGROUP?"

*All* cgroups are hierarchical, so *any* cgroup can (and will) have a "root".

Per the documentation:

> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html
>
> **Creating cgroups and moving processes**
>
> A cgroup filesystem initially contains a single root cgroup, '/',
>   which all processes belong to.  A new cgroup is created by creating a
>   directory in the cgroup filesystem:
>
> ```
> mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cg1
> ```
>
> This creates a new empty cgroup.
>
> A process may be moved to this cgroup by writing its PID into the
>   cgroup's cgroup.procs file:
>
> ```
> echo $$ > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cg1/cgroup.procs
> ```
>
> Only one PID at a time should be written to this file....

Useful articles:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt
- https://medium.com/nttlabs/cgroup-v2-596d035be4d7
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-introduction_to_control_groups